# Status 400 - CakePHP Geocoder Plugin

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, geocoding

Friends, I'm trying to use [this plugin](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-geo) to generate coordinates:

My idea is to register the coordinates of the user at the moment that he inform his address in the registration form. However, I get the error:

**If config is null, key must be an array.**

I read this part of [the documentation](https://github.com/geocoder-php/Geocoder/blob/3.x/README.md#googlemapsbusiness), but I didn't understand how and where to insert an apikey.

I appreciate if anyone can analyze!

Comment: Where are you setting your API key?

Comment: You can also look into https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/awesome-cakephp#geolocation

Comment: $geocodeResult = $this->Geocoder->geocode($location, ['key' => 'my api-key']); => I updated the line as per the documentation, as the status 400 continues.

Comment: Well if `$location` is `null`, as you say, then there's your problem, there's no `location` key/value in your request URLs query string, and you can't query the API without a location, so you need to figure out how to properly pass/access the location from the registration from (usually such form data is being POSTed, and not passed in the query string).

Comment: Now I can pass the address and even inserting the api key returns an error!

Comment: "_an_" error means what error exactly? [**cURL Error (3)**](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html#CURLEURLMALFORMAT)? That means the URL is malformed, make sure that you are showing us the actual URL that you are using.

Comment: Do you have configured your API-Key to use with geolocation-API? Do you have limited your API-Key to any Domain and or IP-Range?

Comment: I installed the package again and read the documentation. By default, it uses the googlemaps provider. Now I get the error: "If config is null, the key must be an array."
I have the key, but I don't understand how and where to insert it. - https://github.com/geocoder-php/Geocoder/blob/3.x/README.md#googlemaps